# Binding Button to its handler by convention doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with caliburn.micro. There is a user control MyView in a tab item of a tab control. Within that user control, there is another tab control. In one of its tabs, I added a button, and a corresponding method with the same name in the MyViewModel. But this method is not called when I click the button. Could you please tell what might cause it?

Thanks.

In the View:

```
            <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}">
...
            <TabItem x:Name="TextTab" Header="Text">

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
...
                        </ScrollViewer>   
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SaveText" Content="Save" Width="50" Height="25" />
                    </Grid>

            </TabItem>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
   public void SaveText()
   {
  ...
   }
```

Comment: I don't see your mentioning any Event call or Command

Comment: Try adding a Binding to an ICommand... or just add a handler in your view that triggers the viewmodel SaveText

Comment: I think using ICommand shouldn't be necessary: "Once again you’ll notice that we don’t need to do much work to hook the click event of the button to the method. For certain user interface controls such as buttons, you can simply set the name of the control to be the name of the method you want it to be hooked to. Caliburn Micro will hook the appropriate event of the user control to the specified method in the model."

Comment: I just had a similar problem. Seems the convention binding is a little bit vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
 <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SaveText" cal:Message.Attach="SaveText" Content="Save" Width="50" Height="25" />
```

Still don't know why the convention didn't work without "Attach".